# Change the orientation of a marker in a 3D scatter plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-maps-markers, orientation, scatter3d

I work on the dynamics of ellipsoidal particles. And I want to visualise how they go about in space using matplotlib. Usually, to represent spherical particles, one can use a scatter plot with marker = 'o', but for ellipsoidal particles, I also want to show how they are oriented in space. I know it is possible to do so for 2D plots one can rotate the marker by specifying an angle, but how can I do this in 3D plots with an orientation that is defined by a vector or a quaternion.

For now, I show the orientation of a particle using quivers to represent the direction of the principal axis. So, something like what you can see below in the plot.

[image: Plot]

But I would like to know if it is possible to take an elongated marker (like  marker= 'd' or 'l') and change the orientation in 3D.